# Laravel 5.7 - eager loading a relationship's relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

How does one go about this? I tried this:

```php
return $this->hasMany(ResolutionLog::class, 'ant_id', 'id')->with('resolutionStatus');
```

and got the error:

> Call to undefined relationship [resolutionLog] on model [App\Models\ResolutionLog].

Or in tinker I'm getting this error when get a `resolutionLog` collection and attempt to access the `resolutionStatus` relationship:

> LogicException with message 'App/Models/ResolutionLog::resolutionStatus must return a relationship instance.'

Here is the `resolutionStatus` relationship on the `ResolutionLog` model:

**ResolutionLog.php**

```php
public function resolutionStatus()
{
    $this->hasOne(ResolutionStatus::class, 'id', 'resolution_status_id');
}
```

And the `resolutionLog` relationship on the `ResolutionStatus` model:

**ResolutionStatus.php**

```php
public function resolutionLog()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ResolutionLog::class, 'resolution_status_id', 'id');
}
```

It should be a one->many relationship between a `ResolutionLog` has one `ResolutionStatus`. A `ResolutionStatus` can have many `ResolutionLog`s.

Answer (score 4):

You should return the relationship, like this:

```
public function resolutionStatus()
{
    // you forgot to return it
    return $this->hasOne(ResolutionStatus::class, 'id', 'resolution_status_id');
}
```

Comment: Holy duh! Good catch :)